# Can I avoid a relation loop in my database design?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I try to design database tables for the case shown below. I also have an account defined, but it's not important regarding my problem.

> There is a list of operations (expenses). Each operation can take place in specified POI, places can be grouped in chains (optional). Each operation can have a recipient, specifically a shop chain.

My current design looks like below. I could even remove chain table in favor of direct reference to recipient, but it still leaves a loop between tables. Effectively, single row could contain references to place and receiving account having different recipient defined.

[image: database design]

The only solution I can see is a table check to exclude described case, but I'm wondering: is there a better fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there isn't anything fundamentally wrong with your design. There's no need to change it just because it contains a loop. The loop in this case doesn't even appear to be a circular dependency. If you believe your current design accurately models what it is intended to then I see no need to change it.

Comment: Any suggestions regarding avoiding data redundancy in this case?

Comment: Just the usual suggestions: understand the fundamentals and do your analysis then apply sensible design principles (Fifth Normal Form, the Principle of Orthogonal Design).